# What is the process to delete a tag?

Tags: support

Specifically, the tag [nois](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nois), which appears to have been created when the tag "noise" wasn't found due to the misspelling. Maybe it's because I'm working on an iPad, but I didn't see any tools to flag an errant tag for review.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just edit the questions to remove an unwanted tag (if it's not as obvious as this case we discuss on meta). Once a tag is removed from all questions, it will still show up as having zero questions tagged until [a daily script runs to hide it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71123/257476)

It's not the case here, but tags will also stay listed with no tagged questions if they have been marked as a synonym of another tag that does have questions.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I removed it with the edit, so it should go away on its own.